# How can I force a UIScrollView to ignore a zoom in gesture completely when already zoomed in fully?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

How can I force a UIScrollView to ignore a pinch open gesture when already zoomed in fully?

The problem I have is that you can drag a scrollview while zooming, even if scrolling is currently disabled. I want to stop that from happening if already zoomed in fully, but still allow zoom out gestures.

Comment: Do you mean cancelling the "bouncing" effect after fully zoomed in/out? There's a property for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `_scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;`